# How to avoid the duplicated data entry after parsing json in kusto?

Tags: kql

I have following sample json data.

```
    {
      "data": {
        "type": "ABC",
        "id": "17495500314",
        "attributes": {
          [!["event": "update",
          "gps_vali][1]][1]d": true,
          "gps": {
            "distance_diff": 6.48,
            "total_distance": 848.6
          },
          "hdop": 79,
          "fuel_level": 46.8,
          "total_fuel_used": 60443.9,
          "location": {
            "latitude": 411.372618,
            "longitude": -1.254931,
            "relative_position": {
              "distance": "37",
              }
          },
          "idle_periods": []
        },
        "relationships": {
          "assets": {
            "data": [
              {
                "type": "ABCDFTTG",
                "id": "1589799143500003",
                "attributes": {
                  "external_id": "ABCDFTTG",
                  "hardware_id": "ABCDFTTG"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "devices": {
            "data": [
              {
                "type": "ABCDFTTG",
                "id": "1585231172900341",
                "attributes": {
                  "serial": "5572016191"
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "tablet",
                "id": "1587893062600175",
                "attributes": {
                  "serial": "ABCDFTTG"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "users": {
            "data": [
              {
                "type": "user",
                "id": "ABCDFTTG",
                "attributes": {
                  "external_id": "ABCDFTTG"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "meta": {
        "message_id": "11eb-8c75-0b3f87aedbb5",
        "consumer_version": "1.2.0",
        "origin_version": null,
        "timestamp": "2021-06-14T17:42:29Z"
      }
    }
```

I want only one row instead of this two. Here is my kusto query which is used for parsing json data into table columns.

```
Test
|where messageId =="123"
//|mv-expand message=message.data.attributes
|mv-expand message
|mv-expand Value=message.data.relationships.assets.['data']
|mv-expand value_devices=message.data.relationships.devices.['data']
|mv-expand value_user=message.data.relationships.users.['data']
| project  type=message.data.type,id=message.data.id,
            event=tostring(message.data.attributes.event),
            logged_at=tostring(message.data.attributes.logged_at),
            distance=toint(message.data.attributes.location.relative_position.distance),
           // Value=message.data.relationships.assets.['data'],//.['data']
            type_asset=Value.type,asset_id=Value.id,
            device_type=value_devices.type,device_id=value_devices.id,
            device_attr_serial=value_devices.attributes.serial,
 user_type=value_user.type,user_id=value_user.id,
user_external_id=value_user.attributes.external_id
```

This duplicate row appeared after adding user tag this tag is array so how to handle this array with single id.

I have parse my json data any got the following output.
[image]

Expected output should be like

[image]

check device_type and device_id columns

Comment: Why did you revert my edit? Now, your post is wrongly formatted again?

Comment: hey i am trying to format my question bt still i doesn't seems good  :(

Comment: No problem. Let me help you. Just a sec.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Please edit to provide minimal sample input in datatable format, and expected output.